# How to parse Apache Catalina.log

Tags: regex, apache, tomcat

I am trying to find a way to parse a Catalina.log and i am really struggling.

**This a piece of the code:**

```
    May 12, 2017 2:14:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-10.1.31.104-443"]
java.lang.Exception: Connector attribute SSLCertificateFile must be defined when using SSL with APR
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:490)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:649)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:821)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:427)
```

**I wanna get**

**Date** = May 12, 2017 2:14:38 PM

**class** = org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

**Error level** = SEVERE

**Error Msg** = Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-10.1.321.224-443"]

**Error Msg Body** = java.lang.Exception: Connector attribute SSLCertificateFile must be defined when using SSL with APR
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:490)....

i don even know where to start :) 
any ideas are very welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have prepared for you the following regex:

```
((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s(AM|PM))\s(.+)(\r)?\n(FATAL|SEVERE|ERROR|WARN(ING)?|INFO|CONFIG|INFO|DEBUG):\s(.+)(\r)?\n(.+)(\r)?\n(?=\s+at.+java:\d+\))
```

You can use the following back reference to capture your groups

```
DATE -> $1
CLASS ->  $4
ERROR_LEVEL ->  $6
ERROR_MSG ->  $8
ERROR_BODY ->  $10
```

The regex will only fetch strings that met the following conditions:

- starts by a date in the format specified in your post
- after the date, the first line is composed of the class name
- the 2nd line is composed of the error level and the error msg
- the 3rd line is your error msg body
- followed by a java strack trace of n lines starting by \s at and ending by java:\d+)

The regex works in the following way:

```
((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s(AM|PM))
```

This part will fetch the date **in the format of your post**:

3 char month followed by space(s) then 1 or 2 digits, ',' then year in 4 digit
then space(s), then time(column char, followed by space(s) then AM or PM

```
\s(.+)(\r)?\n
```

this part of the regex will allow you to get the rest of your first line corresponding to your **class**

```
(FATAL|SEVERE|ERROR|WARN(ING)?|INFO|CONFIG|INFO|DEBUG):\s(.+)(\r)?\n(.+)(\r)?\n
```

This part will allow you to get the **error level** (in this exhaustive list) followed by column and the following 2 lines corresponding **to your error msg/body**

```
(?=\s+at.+java:\d+\))
```

This last part is a condition the enforce that your error is followed by a java stack trace.

You might need to adapt a bit some parts of the regex (like the number of lines of the error body, error message) or the stack trace conditions but I think this is a great starting point for your case.

CHEERS!!!